# apostrophe in org-babel export to latex and beamer

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, org-export

How can I get org-babel to properly render ' and not ’ when exporting to LaTeX and to Beamer?
I didn't find any good solution yet, and I would like the code to be copy-pasteable.

Answer (score 3):

Smart quotes render `'text'` as `` `text' `` in LaTeX.

That can be done in following ways.

#### Enable smart quotes for all exports

Put this in your `init.el` after loading org-mode.

```
(setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t)
```

#### Enable smart quotes on export only a particular org file

Put this in the beginning of the org file.

```
#+OPTIONS: ':t
```

#### References

- [org-export-with-smart-quotes](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/org-export-with-smart-quotes)
- [org-export-smart-quotes-alist](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/org-export-smart-quotes-alist)
- [org-export-smart-quotes-regexps](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/org-export-smart-quotes-regexps)

Comment: I tried this solution but still get the same issue.

Comment: Actually I notice that, even without (setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t) it renders ' for html but not for latex nor beamer exports.

Comment: @mhartm I thought of smartquotes and upquotes as the same. The second solution should resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question when writing my first answer. Here's a second try, tested out.

#### Solution

You need to use a combination of `alltt` and `upquote` latex packages. Here is my solution based on the below referenced solutions from TeX SE and the use of org-mode [Macro Replacement](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html).

The below MWE was tested on `emacs -Q`, emacs 24.4.

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{alltt}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{upquote}

#+LaTeX_HEADER: \makeatletter
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \newcommand*{\textalltt}{}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \DeclareRobustCommand*{\textalltt}{%
#+LaTeX_HEADER:   \begingroup
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \let\do\@makeother
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \dospecials
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \catcode`\\=\z@
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \catcode`\{=\@ne
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \catcode`\}=\tw@
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \verbatim@font\@noligs
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \@vobeyspaces
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \frenchspacing
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     \@textalltt
#+LaTeX_HEADER: }
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \newcommand*{\@textalltt}[1]{%
#+LaTeX_HEADER:     #1%
#+LaTeX_HEADER:   \endgroup
#+LaTeX_HEADER: }
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \makeatother

#+MACRO: UPQUOTE @@latex:\textalltt{'}@@

Without upquotes: 'How' about this?

With upquotes: {{{UPQUOTE}}}How{{{UPQUOTE}}} about this?
```

[image]

#### Requirements

- `alltt` and `upquote` LaTeX packages. *If you use TexLive, you can do `tlmgr install alltt` and `tlmgr install upquote`.*

#### References

- How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX - [TeX-SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63345/how-to-make-a-real-apostrophe-or-single-quote-in-latex)
- alltt package's \alltt{} makes a newline - [TeX-SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/alltt-packages-alltt-makes-a-newline)

Comment: Thanks, but I want upquotes always to be upquotes, like when text is exported to html. I don't want to add {{{UPQUOTE}}} each time...